# How do I skip the first element from a String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

How do I skip the first element from a String Array?

Comment: Well yeah but the problem is that I can't delete the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another quick approach is to control the line reads through flag like below:

```
public List<Beruf> fileRead(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<Beruf> berufe = new ArrayList<Beruf>();
    String line = "";
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        Boolean firstLine = Boolean.TRUE;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(firstLine) {
                firstLine = Boolean.FALSE;
                continue;
            }
            String[] attributes = line.split(";");
            Beruf beruf = createBeruf(attributes);
            berufe.add(beruf);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return berufe;
}
```

Comment: If i use your way I got this kind of output: packagename.Beruf@2c715e84 or packagename.Beruf@d78795

Comment: Weird I think this solution should also work just fine.

Comment: @Philand, solution has noting to do with screen out, it is just skipping first iteration from the loop.

Comment: Well found the problem :D was a little upsi from my side. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to remove the header line would be to just read it before you enter your while loop.

```
String filePath = path;
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
                
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String headers = reader.readLine(); //This removes the first line from the BufferedReader
            
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] attributes = line.split(";");
      Beruf beruf = createBeruf(attributes);
      berufe.add(beruf);
 }
reader.close();
```

If you use java 8 or higher and are allowed to use streams you could also use the `lines` method of the `Files` class

```
       Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))
                .skip(1) // skipping the headers
                .map(line -> line.split(";"))
                .map(attributes -> createBeruf(attributes))
                .forEach(beruf -> berufe.add(beruf));
```